# Asker answered their own question after they already accepted an earlier answer

Tags: discussion, downvotes, not-an-answer

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70635026/scipy-optimize-minimize-objective-function-must-return-a-scalar) today, in which the asker had already accepted an answer and then posted their reply as an answer (repeating the same thing as the first answerer).

Should I flag the asker's answer (as not-an-answer) or should I just downvote their answer?

I tend to flag it, but I would like to have your opinions.

Comment: Why do you feel that the answer isn't an answer? It *looks* like an answer.

Comment: Though if I am honest, the entire thing looks like it could be classed as a typographical error, as it looks like the only problem was the placement of a right parenthesis (`)`.

Comment: @Larnu: It's stating the exact same thing as the accepted answer, just with less details. I'm not sure though if it should be deleted. The question should be closed as a typo question.

Comment: @Larnu It actually is an answer but after already getting the answer, the asker's reply (as an answer) was spam to me (just in my opinion) and that's why I wanted other opinions as well.

Comment: My point is, however, is that putting the *same* answer doesn't make an answer not an answer; a "not an answer" flag on it would be declined @BDL as it clearly *is* an answer (just a lower quality one). But I did agree on the typographical error side on things.

Comment: Closing the question will not prevent the unwanted answer from being downvoted for being irrelevant, deleting the answer would be a lesson and a helping hand to the author really.

Comment: Spam also has a specific meaning here on [so], @MuhammadMohsinKhan . The answer is *not* spam.

Comment: NAA has a strict definition: not an attempt to answer. Please do not flag posts like the one in question as NAA, this is not what the flag is for. Others are correct, though - it is a typo question and should be closed (as it is now) as such. Answers that add no value can be requested for deletion by users with the privilege in SOCVR (but please follow the rules of the room). Answers that copy other answers without proper credit can be flagged for mod attention for plagiarism, but it does not look like this is the case here. Pretty straightforward workflow if you ask me.

Comment: According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), duplicate answers should be deleted/flagged for deletion. The help center article defines this as "exact duplicate", but one could argue that an answer that does not add anything new is semantically an exact duplicate (instead of requiring a 100% identical copy of another answer). This interpretation is used on various other SE sites and is IMO useful to keep the Q&A clean.

Comment: Thanks for the insights guys. @Marijn Yes, it was not exactly duplicate but it actually didn't add anything new as well and in that context was duplicate. That's why I discussed the issue here.

Comment: Side note, @MuhammadMohsinKhan , please don't assume the gender of a user. Yes, the user in question has a profile picture of what appears to be a man, but that doesn't mean they are. The user doesn't call out they identify as a man, and so (per the code of conduct) you should use gender neutral language.

Comment: @Larnu Duly noted!

Comment: “Should I flag the asker's answer (as not-an-answer) or should I just downvote their answer?” - Does it answer the question, if so, it would be inappropriate to downvote it.  If it’s commentary submitted as an answer then downvote it and vote to delete it. If the question was caused by a typo, vote to close, and downvote the question.

Comment: @SecurityHound So a low quality or a duplicate answer or an answer without an effort can't be downvoted?

Comment: @Muhammad - Who said it was low quality? The answer in question was deleted. I made it clear, if the answer is clearly commentary, it should be downvoted. You didn’t provide a screenshot of the answer, so I have no frame of reference, in this particular case

Comment: The first answer was posted at Jan 8 at 18:11, OP's own answer was posted  Jan 8 at 18:12, i.e. somewhere between a few seconds and 2 minutes later. It's quite possible OP hadn't seen the first answer when he answered his own question. No need to be harsh in such situations.

Comment: The user who posted the answer isn't relevant, treat it as a standalone post. Would you downvote if it was posted by someone else?

Comment: @DavidG What if it is a duplicate? or commentary?

Comment: The same rule applies as you would any other post, the name of the user who posted it is still not relevant.

Comment: Side note, @MuhammadMohsinKhan: As explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/415333/1835379), you weren't _wrong_ to use "he" in the original revision of this post.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sometimes askers will reframe an answer to be more explicit about how it helped their specific situation.  I don't see anything wrong with that.  I probably wouldn't upvote it though, so the original answer will still show higher.

Answer (score 14):

There was less than 30 seconds between the first answer and theirs. They most likely didn't copy it, but just found the error themselves, and posted their answer at roughly the same time.

Which was then nagged, downvoted to hell and deleted, because, alas, there was much judgement, and little checking of timestamps.

Answer (score 9):

There are valid reasons to do so, for example:

- finding out about a more efficient way to do it.
- finding the exact documentation one was looking for.

Answers may draw content from another answers. When referring to the original answer and providing an alternation to it, this is generally being welcome (one can do this instead of editing other "known to be working" answers) - but not when blatantly copying it, without any reference or real difference (duplicate content). Clearly stating the difference suggested.

Answer (score 5):

#### Dialogue before sanctions.

If the timing of the answer and the fact the question was due to a typo were not the issue here, and you would be considering a downvote or a flag, I would suggest not rushing to downvote, let alone bothering moderators with a flag: First, comment on the new answer, point out it is an apparent dupe of the existing one, and see what the person says. **Maybe there is some information/circumstances which you are missing.** In this case, you would likely have been told about the timing. In another case, it may be pointed out that the new answer frames things different (as @MarkRansom suggests). And if you don't "buy" their reply, or they don't reply - then proceed to downvote.

PS - If it's not you that downvotes, somebody else probably will, so don't worry about forgetting to check back and downvote.

Answer (score 3):

This meta question's premise is different than the example linked.

**Premise**

Can an asker answer their own question after accepting a different answer? Of course.

**Linked Example**

The asker takes an answer which inadvertently corrected a minor typo<sup>1</sup>, then poses their own answer stating the typo was the entirety of the problem... this is not ideal for numerous reasons: if the question merely addresses a typo, it should be closed; taking a small part of another answer and directly making it your own is borderline plagiarism in general, and here is just needless; the whole acknowledgement of the other answer fixing the issue should have been a comment on the answer; etc... this was clearly just a mess.

The post has since been rightly deleted.

---

<sub>1. The answerer did not state the typo was corrected, but had fixed it during coding their suggested solution</sub>

Comment: Are you suggesting possible plagiarism by the OP of the linked question in their answer? If not, it seems completely unnecessary to mention it at all, especially given the timelines of the two answers. And while there can obviously be different forms and degrees of plagiarism, I don't understand what you mean by _"borderline plagiarism"_. What is that?

Comment: @skomisa - There is kind of a gray area for plagiarism with the first set of characters. Something like <18 starts to get wonky. This was "get_ret(weights)[2]", or 19 characters.. and to be honest I don't consider that to be really be plagiarism, *as stated*, it is just unnecessary to do that in this case, to reproduce the given answer, for the aforementioned reasons. That is what I am referring to specifically here. Now, broadly, if someone were to go cherry pick 4 or 5 lines of code from another answer, and then form their own unsourced answer from that... that would be pushing the line.

Comment: That was my main point. Here, it was unnecessary, but in general, taking code from other answers and using it verbatim in yours... at some point it becomes plagiarism if the content copied becomes significant.

Answer (score 3):

> Should I flag the asker's answer (as not-an-answer) or should I just downvote their answer?

Each answer should be judged on its own merit, including self-answers.  Self answers are allowed,

- including when there are other answers,
- including when the OP accepts another answer,
- including when they accept another answer before posting their own,
- even when (which did not happen in the example case) they then change the accepted answer to their own.

None of that is in itself a reason to downvote, much less flag.

In the particular case linked, it's not even clear that the OP wrote their self-answer with reference to the other.  The two were posted within about a minute of each other.

However, both answers do conclude that the problem is addressed by a very small rearrangement of the code of one line. Thus, the problem is reasonably categorized as arising from a syntax error, and as such, *neither* answer should have been posted.  The OP should probably have deleted the question, and the other answerer should have commented and voted to close instead of answering.

The question now *has* been closed as arising from a typo, so meta came to the rescue there, and it has even been deleted, which seems a bit overkill, but also no big loss.

Answer (score 1):

There's a "Self-Learner" badge, which is earned when the following criteria is met: "Answer your own question with score of 3 or more". It's quite possible that the asker was going on a badge-hunt.

Someone could easily be motivated to perform certain actions for getting points/badges, even if the actions were performed in a dishonorable way.