# Is it really wrong to use gendered pronoun about users with a gendered avatar or username?

Tags: discussion, users, gender

On this Meta site (much less reason to write about specific users that way on the main site and if yes, the username or "OP" is used), is it really that wrong to use "he" or "she" when mentioning someone who uses a picture of a male or female person (and not an obvious celebrity) or whose username is clearly male or female (again, clearly like John, not ambiguous like Andrea)? Highly upvotes comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415286/asker-answered-their-own-question-after-they-already-accepted-an-earlier-answer?cb=1) seem to claim so for the avatar. Does a person have to specify their gender explicitly?

Comment: That topic is a real mine field, so I wouldn't suggest to assume the gender from the avatar or the name and always use gender neutral language. Some users may mention their pronouns in their profile, but I'm to lazy to check for them just to use specific pronouns.

Comment: IMO, No, it's not, but if they correct you, apologize and move on, there's nothing else that really needs to be said about it. Just act like a decent human.

Comment: Well, this is not really about me, I normally use the user name.

Comment: I have an avatar of my friend. I told them "be there or be square". You can't assume the person in picture is the actual users behind the screen

Comment: @Nick: I don't think _anyone_ has to __apologize__ for the use of a gendered pronoun if the avatar is obvious in that regard. This specific case talks about a profile picture, which is a headshot of what's obviously a dude, stubble and all. I mean, if said user _cares_ about not being called a "he", he'd have something about it in his profile. I mean, there's being neutral, and there's going out of the way to make a political statement. In this specific case, I think both the comment and the "neutralizing" edit were excessive.

Comment: @Cerbrus In honesty I meant a token gesture of "Oh, sorry", effectively more of an _acknowledgement_ of wrongdoing. Sincere apologies only make sense IMO when the offense is caused in a situation it was more likely.

Comment: @Nick: Yea, something like "Ok, I'll keep that in mind" makes more sense, imo.

Comment: (So, to clarify, you shouldn't feel _guilty_ for assuming a profile pic of a dude represents a dude)

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong with it - just stand corrected if told the preferred one (or fall back to gender-neutral language). *Never* feel the need to apologize for the assumption unless it should have been clear from the context (other conversations in the same thread, posts, and such).

Comment: My comment was deleted but I will repeat it in more word and detail. The comments all say what I should do and votes punish me for what they think I do or because I am surely a bigot or who knows. This is about the rules and the etiquette. It is about whether other users (not me) should be reminded they should not use he when mentioning a user with an obvious bloke avatar. Please do not say that I should do this or that. So what users may or may not in general. I, personally, normally cannot run i.to this issue anyway, because I strive to address users by their (user) name.

Comment: Votes do not "punish" you.

Comment: @VladimirF I do not think the comments refer to what *you*, specifically (at least mine doesn't), should do but rather signify what others feel is the correct way to proceed. As for the votes, well... 'tis the topic that strikes the bare nerve for some countries - I do not think it is possible to construct a post about such matters without causing at least *some* level of controversy.

Comment: @E_net4isnotinaforum These look very much so. This is not a feature proposal where votes show disagreement with the proposal. Here it very much looks like the voters assume something about me personally.

Comment: @Vladimir this is not the case - despite the official stance that the cotes of disagreement are expressed on FR posts, it is not true at all de facto. Voting is much more free-shaped on meta than on main. There is no need to assume anything about voters either - it might very well be that someone just did not see the issue as improtant, or just lost their keys.

Comment: This question already has 1 pretty good answer.  If you would like to provide your own, please do, but do so as an answer.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Quoting from the [answers to the FAQ post about pronouns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336365/348196) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> #### 4. Can I use he or she based on a user name/avatar and correct if they tell me I was wrong?
>
> We do not recommend assuming people's gender, **but you can do so**. If someone corrects you with their stated pronouns, please start using the stated ones instead.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

A little anecdote. I am a gamer. I am a male. If given the choice of gender in a game, I tend to choose a woman. Or a cat! Whatever non-male options are available. I don't want to play as myself so I pick something far removed from myself. Escapism for the win.

So given that little sidetrack, let's take the Stack Overflow avatar and username. Frankly I don't want my avatar to have anything to do with me in real life either. If interactions on this site extend to your personal life / work life / social media, people can be persistent and it's a little unnerving. So whatever name and picture you see... it is just as likely to be a complete facade.

So do what you want, but I personally would not assume anything. And to be honest... using the gender-neutral terminology is just so wonderfully simple once you get used to it. I wouldn't know why you would want to make your life more difficult by just having to refer to a gender. All you can see is unicode text anyway.

Comment: And you or do not feel offended if someone addresses your female character or alter ego as a female? That is the point. The point is the gender you are going with, not what genitals you have on your physical body.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I make an active effort to not be offended. And also to not trigger people who are looking to be offended... by only applying gender-neutral terminology. Frankly, I really don't know what you were hoping to achieve with that comment.

Comment: I do not understand what you wanted to achieve with this answer. It seems to me obvious that if one acts as a gender different from their physical sex that they want to be addressed in the gender they use. I do not understand why the fact they they are actually someone else should be relevant at all. If I post here as a cat, I can be addressed as a cat, unless I tell people to do otherwise. That's it.